# Increase the count in setter method for a property in c#

Tags: c#, increment

In a `class` I have declared one `property` like below

```
class MyClass
{
    public string TName
    {
         get {return "";}
    }

    // and some other properties ....
}
```

One method is returning the type `IEnumerable<MyClass>`, here I want to get the `TName` value as

```
Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4........
```

based on the count.

**Problem:**

How can I *increment* the value of counter in my `setter` method of the above property, so that i can append like `"Name" + counter;`

Or is there any other better way to achieve this without `looping` and `fetching` the count from `DB`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this class persisted in the DB? Do you have an `Id` or `Count` property that is set to auto-increment on the DB?

Comment: I'd suggest that you think about renaming that from `TName` to `Name`.  A capital T is usually put at the beginning of generic type names and would be confusing in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same idea (we have a counter `s_Count`) but in case you want it *thread safe* we have to increment it in a special way:

```
class MyClass {
  private static int s_Count;

  public string TName {
    get;
  }

  public MyClass() {
    TName = $"Name {Interlocked.Increment(ref s_Count)}";
  }    
}
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine as it will give the exact same value per instance, independent on how many instances were created meanwhile.

Answer (score 3):

You need a static counter within `MyClass` that contains the number of instances that were already created:

```
class MyClass
{
    static int count = 0;
    public MyClass() { count++; }
}
```

Now you can easily access that counter within your `Name`-property:

```
string Name { get => $"Name{ counter }"; }
```

If there are multple threads that may concurrently increment the `counter` it´s better to use [`Interlocked.Increment(ref count)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) instead of `count++` within the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to store the value of `TName` in a private string;

```
private string m_TName;
public string TName
{
    get {return m_TName + counter;}
    set {
        if (m_TName != value){
            m_TName = value
        }
    }
}
```

if `TName` is always the same you can use

```
private string m_TName = "Default value";
public string TName
{
    get {return m_TName + counter;}
}
```

if you want to increment the counter each call

```
private string m_TName = "Default value";
public string TName
{
    get { 
        counter++;
        return m_TName + counter;
    }
}
```

if you want it on every instance as per HimBromBeere's comment

```
private string m_TName;
public string TName
{
    get {return m_TName;}
    set {
        if (m_TName != value){
            counter++;
            m_TName = value + counter;
        }
    }
}
```

if you want it on every instance as per HimBromBeere's comment AND you only want to set it once

```
private string m_TName;
public string TName
{
    get {return m_TName;}
    set {
        if (m_TName != value && m_TName == null){
            counter++;
            m_TName = value + counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt OP wants to increase the counter on every call, but on every *instance* instead.

Comment: if that's the case your answer is better